# sed + delete line only if line  ended with specific character

Tags: solaris, sed

need help  - how to delete the line from the file if the last char is - ":" with sed , on Solaris machine

for example sed will remove the following line (include the black line)

```
      /etc/val/config/globals.xml:/globals/CLUSTERNODES/node:
```

example what not need to delete

```
      /etc/val/config/globals.xml:/globals/CLUSTERNODES/node:node1a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -e '/:$/d' < foo > foo.new
```

will do the job (just tested it on Solaris 8, and it seems fine).